# Avisynth like NonLinear Editor for Linux

Tags: video-processing, red5, video-editing, avisynth

In my Red5 application, I need a tool that can take 4 video streams and merge them into one bigger video in a 2x2 grid (like security camera videos). Avisynth’s script seem easy to use however:

- it doesn’t generate output (a new video file with the NLE commands applied)
- it doesn’t work on linux

is there some NLE frameserver for linux that can run scripts and give me output files?

Comment: Avisynth works fine on my Linux Ubuntu 10.04 (via `wine`)..

Comment: actually I have been looking for something that could be run from a server, through code. I have had some success with Xuggle, but still trying...

Comment: [VapourSynth](http://www.vapoursynth.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in real-time you can use Xuggle. There are some demos floating around which show side by side displays of two videos ( I believe one is original and the second is a filtered copy). At one point the author of Xuggle was working on a commercial version which touted this feature.

If you are doing this strictly as playback on stored video you can use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/). There are numerous questions about this on SO.

- [FFMPEG 2 Videos transcoded and side by side in 1 frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293265/ffmpeg-2-videos-transcoded-and-side-by-side-in-1-frame)
- [FFMPEG - errors when combining videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590221/ffmpeg-errors-when-combining-videos)