# OpenCV - Dragging image blocks in a window

Tags: opencv

I am trying to make a jigsaw puzzle game in OpenCV. What i am doing is that i am converting an image into small squares which are images of equal dimensions. For example if i have an image of A x B size, then i re-size it to 640 x 640 and divide this re-sized image into squares each of which are of 64 x 64 size. I save these square images on the local disk.

Now i want to know if it is possible to place these square images randomly in one window and drag these images to match the final winning state? I can't find a way to implement the drag and drop thing. It'll be great if i can get some hints on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OpenCV can't display multiple images on the same window** (natively). However, you can write a code that [assembles all these little images into one large image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14638038/176769), and then display that on a window.

The downside of this approach is that you will have to store an array with the information of where those images are placed (geographically speaking), so when a user clicks on the middle of the screen you can tell exactly which image is on that position. But you'll also have some major headaches to write the *drag&drop* animations because there's no way to do that with what OpenCV offers.

There are some demos laying around that shows how to deal with mouse clicks on OpenCV:

- [Display pixel coordinate values based on the mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14918425/176769)
- [MouseCallback Function OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14633072/176769)
- [Draw on webcam using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493633/176769)
- [Setting ROI with mouse from a rectangle on a video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10883266/176769)
- [Free form image selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196180/176769)

Bottom line, **OpenCV is not built for these types of user interactions**. I suggest you investigate **Qt** or some other technology to build your game.

I remember seeing a Qt demo that achieves what you are looking for:

- [Draggable Icons Example](http://apidocs.meego.com/1.2/qt4/draganddrop-draggableicons.html)

Comment: already tried but up-voting requires at least 15 reputations. :)

Comment: Alright, no problem. Stick around and you will eventually get more reputation. It's a good practice to click on the checkbox near an answer to select it as the official problem solver. By doing this you will be helping future visitors. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

i'm too lazy to write your program, but here are some parts you might like:

the mouse:

```
void onmouse(int event, int x, int y, int mousestate, void *userptr)
{
    if (event==1) // lmousebuttondown, do something with x, y
}

namedWindow("win");
setMouseCallback( "win", onmouse );
```

and, painting a small image(the thing you dragged) imto the big one:

```
Rect r(x,y,small.cols, small.rows);
big(r) = small;
```