# ffmpeg split screen from mjpeg error

Tags: ffmpeg

I know it may be possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293265/ffmpeg-2-videos-transcoded-and-side-by-side-in-1-frame), but...

I'm trying to use answer given there like this:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i http://xxx:8080/video -i http://yyy:8080/video -filter_complex "[0:v] scale=iw/2:ih/2, pad=2*iw:ih [left]; [1:v] scale=iw/3:ih/3, fade=out:300:30:alpha=1[right]; [left][right] overlay=main_w/2:0 [out]" -b:v 768k Output.mp4
```

But getting an error:

> Output pad "default" with type video of the filter instance
>   "Parsed_overlay_4" of overlay not connected to any destination

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution...

Had to add `-map "[out]"` param and it works!